# How to Link Google domain to 5gbfree hosting

Tags: dns, web, hosting

I purchased a Domain from google and got 5 gb space from 5gbfree hosting website how should i now connect the domain to host?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the DNS in the domain control panel.
For the DNS you can check the same in your hosting control panel.

If you are not able to find the DNS, then you can check for the IP(A-record) in your hosting control panel and update the same in the DNS manager of your domain control panel

The DNS can be updated from the DNS Manager in the provided domain control panel.

I hope it helps.